# In r, how to save plot and reuse the plot code

Tags: r, plot

The following code is a minimal example of what I have and what I am trying to achieve. The idea is I have a large chunk of code that builds up a plot in many steps. I want to save the plot as a png at different steps along the way.

This chunk works...

```
x<-runif(10)
y<-runif(10)

png(filename="Plot0.png")
plot(y~x)
abline(h=mean(y))
dev.off()
```

but when I split the plot chunks yet want to save each step individually there's a problem.

```
x<-runif(10)
y<-runif(10)

png(filename="Plot1.png")
plot(y~x)
dev.off()

png(filename="Plot2.png")
abline(h=mean(y))
dev.off()
```

The problem is `plot.new has not been called yet`. This I have searched but I can't seem to find the bits that make it work.

Comment: Did you try `plot.new` ???

Comment: How and where should I try this? (I did try many combinations but I just couldn't get it to work)

Comment: @cory That won't work

Comment: Perhaps worth looking at: https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2016/12/08/save-base-graphics-as-pseudo-objects-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

R handles basic plot that `plot` creates a new "sheet of paper" and other function such as `abline` can draw on top of it. Thus you cannot use `abline` without calling a plot first. You called `dev.off` which clears the previous plot, and therefore you don't have any plot to use `abline` with -> `plot.new has not been called yet`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to switch to the grid system to enable this.

You might want to consider switching to ggplot and saving the object along the way, or using ggsave.

Here's a solution using graphics which basically captures your base R plot on grid:

```
library(graphics)

x<-runif(10)
y<-runif(10)

plot(y~x)
pl <- recordPlot()

png(filename="Plot1.png")
grid::grid.newpage()
pl
dev.off()

abline(h=mean(y))
pl <- recordPlot()
png(filename="Plot2.png")
grid::grid.newpage()
pl
dev.off()
```

In ggplot, you can simply do:

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(
x<-runif(10),
y<-runif(10)
)    

g = ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()+theme_bw()
ggsave(g,file="Plot1.png")
g = g + geom_hline(yintercept=mean(y))
ggsave(g,file="Plot2.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the link given by duckmayr in the original question comments I was able to achieve the desired result. Throughout a construction one can simply include say `p1<-recordplot()` and then create the png of `p1` at the end. I think that this is rather elegant.

```
x<-runif(10)
y<-runif(10)


dev.control(displaylist="enable")
  plot(y~x)
p1 <- recordPlot()
  abline(h=mean(y))
p2 <- recordPlot()
invisible(dev.off())

png(filename="Plot1.png")
p1
dev.off()

png(filename="Plot2.png")
p2
dev.off()
```